# How to extract data from software?

Tags: automation, reverse-engineering

I have a software that consist of list of domestic companies, and when you double click on a company, you get some data about it. 
It has no API.

Is it possible to somehow make a script that will get those data and put it in my database.

I'm not expecting a full on tutorial. But, can someone please point me out to the right direction.

Comment: without knowing what does the software do to extract the data (the algorithm it uses and the data sources) you will not be able to reproduce the results on your own. Unless you know what the program does.

Comment: The data is extracted from the dat file that goes with it. And, by disassembling the exe, I would say it's mySQL database, as I saw some mysql commands.

Comment: So why don't you just dump the content of the mySQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pull the data from the software user interface, though it will be slower than if you can just extract it from wherever it stores it.

Without any detail about the software, I'll assume for now it's a native Windows application which displays the data you want to grab in a text field when you double click on a company displayed in a simple list control.

To harvest data from such an application, you could use a scriptable UI automation tool such as [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/), to repeatedly send the necessary UI events to the software to simulate an user displaying the companies:

- [Set the focus](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlFocus.htm) on the company list control
- Select the next company (maybe by [sending an arrow key event](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm))
- [Send a double click event](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm), there are alternative ways of doing this depending on the kind of control which displays the company list.
- Wait for the text field to show up or get filled with new data (you can wait for events, poll the field contents, poll the window controls, wait for a popup window, ...)
- [Get the text field contents](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlGetText.htm).
- Write it somewhere (maybe to a [file](http://ahkscript.org/docs/objects/File.htm))
- Repeat

Once you're done, inject the file in your database.

There is a variety of UI automation tools for other kinds of UIs, if your software is not a native Windows application. They tend to be used for QA, but can also help to pull data from an application to which you have limited access.

Comment: Thank you. That's extactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to figure out the format of the data file, and write your own program to retrieve data from it.

SQLite is extremely popular, so the .dat file might be in SQLite format:

https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html

If that's the case, you should be able to interactively inspect the DB using a SQLite client, and figure out how to extract your data - here's a command line example:

```
$ sqlite3 foo.dat
sqlite> .databases
    < Database list should appear here >
sqlite> .tables
    < Table list should appear here >
```

And so on.